# Accessing a updated variable declared in a file from multiple files in php

Tags: php, file-io

I have declared a variable array in a php file ,and changing its value of the array after including the file. Then, after changing I want the array variable will have updated values, so that if I access it from a third file , I will get the new array values. How can I do it?
I am required it from a online quiz page. I fetched random problems whenever a user load the page from database. After submitting, for displaying result, I require the id number of the fetched problems in the submit.php page(the page redirected after submitting). I have stored the problems id in an array in the problem page , and I wanted the array to be accessible from the submit.php page.

Comment: It sounds like you want to globally store a variable. You can do so by writing to files or saving in databases. Keep in mind that whenever you include a file, its contents are basically executed, so if the variable is initialized in the variable-file, then that's something permanent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon what behavior you want for your array.

If it is an array that is specific to an instance of someone browsing your web application, where each person has their own variable to do with as they please, then you'll probably want to set it using sessions, and the `$_SESSION` global variable.
Maybe something like this:

```
//file1.php
<?php
    session_name("applicationName"); //give your session a unique and static name, so that other apps on your server don't interfere
    session_start(); //must always start the session before working with session variables
    $_SESSION['data'] = array(1, 3, 6, 9); //set your array into the session global
    include("file2.php");
?>

//file2.php
<?php
    $_SESSION['data'][0]++; //for demonstration purposes, increment the first key of the array
?>

//file3.php
<?php
    session_name("applicationName"); //same session name
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION['data']); //shows the contents of your array,
        //which will now contain 2, 3, 6, 9
?>
```

However, if the data in the array should be globally accessible by anybody accessing your application, you might want to look into using a database, or APC to store your array.  The danger with simply using a flat file is that one user may cause a write action while another is causing a read action, which may cause unpredictable results.  Databases like MySQL and caching extensions like APC operate mostly on a first-come first-serve basis, and do not suffer from this issue.

If your data is important, use a database, as the data will survive a server restart:

```
//store the variable to a row in the database
$query = $dbconn->query("INSERT INTO tblVariables(variableName, variableValue)
    VALUES ('someVariable', '".$dbconn->real_escape_string(serialize($yourArray))."';");

//retrieve the variable from that row
$query = $dbconn->query("SELECT variableValue FROM tblVariables WHERE variableName = 'someVariable';");
if($query) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        $yourArray = deserialize($row['variableValue']);
}
```

`serialize()`/`deserialize()` is a handy way of consolidating an array or an object into a single storable string.  Make sure the database column it's being stored in is `VARCHAR` of sufficient size, or `TEXT`.

If your data is temporary in nature, APC can do the trick, provided it's available on your server:

```
//store the array in APC
apc_store('variableName', $yourArray);

//retrieve the array from APC
$yourArray = apc_fetch('variableName');
```

APC does not require that you use `serialize()`.

You'll have to work out what goes where in your application for the database or APC, but the session example should be enough to give you an idea of how to organize your code, based upon your question.